# Qt how to open a file in current dir ? or what's wrong with this?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I'm trying to open an xml file in the current location of the executable

```
        QString path = QDir::currentPath();
        path.append("/acc.xml");
        QFile file(path);

        if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        {
            insertItem("IO ERR");
        }
```

- When I run it from Qt creator, everything works. `currentPath()` returns the path to the executable's folder
- When I go to `project-build-desktop/` folder and try to run it manually `currentPath()` returns `/home/user/Documents`

**EDIT**

also tried with same results:

```
Qt::current().path();
Qt::current().absolutePath();
```

Comment: The problem obviously comes from the path of the document.

Comment: What's the correct way ? I've spent already almost 2 hours trying to figure out / understand Qt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() instead of QDir::currentPath().

For details see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath

Answer (score 2):

Check the returned value of `QDir::currentPath()`. I think when you run from Qt Creator, it returns the path where the project file (*.pro) is located. When you run from outside, you get path of the binary.

**Edit**

I never worked with Linux. However, you can try other functions/combinations from `QDir`:

- QDir::current().path()
- QDir::current().absolutePath()

etc.

Comment: from outside it's `/home/user/Documents`. But the executable I'm running is clearly not there...

Comment: I actually need the path to the binary... and that's not happening when I run it from outside

Comment: same results. From Qt-Creator - OK, outside - NOT.

Comment: @Vic.: on windows using Qt in an application, each time the application starts, it creates a directory (if not present) where the binary is present. I'll let you know how I did that when I get back to home. As far as I remember, it is QDir::current().mkdir("saves"). And it worked with Qt Creator and outside of it alike.

Comment: @Vic.: sorry, i use 'QDir().mkdir(_path);' to create the directory.

Comment: meh.. anyway.. today I got disappointed in linux.. just one more time.. let's see how long it takes me to make a pop3 client

Answer (score 2):

To open a file in the current directory, you simply call QFile constructor

I tested this on my Linux machine and it works

```
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    QFile some_file("test.xml");
    if(!some_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        qDebug() << "Unable to open file";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "File open successfully";
    }
    exit(-1);
}
```

I run ./TestQFile and if there is a test.xml in the current directory, it works.

UPDATE: I notice that the wording of your question says that you want the file in the same directory as the executable, this can be done as follow:

```
// Getting directory of the executable
QFileInfo exec_fileinfo(argv[0]);
qDebug() << "Executable is in" << exec_fileinfo.absolutePath();
```

UPDATE 2: Under the project panel of QtCreator, there is a field for Working Directory. This is the directory that is returned by QDir::currentPath() if you are running it via QtCreator.

Comment: I didn't use QtCreator to code this up. Can you give more details on your directory structure and the exact command that you ran to reproduce the file open error?

Comment: It seems that QtCreator does some kind of `magic` when running my project. It's a GUI application that I'm trying to design. From `outside` I usually run the application with no arguments, just `click`

Comment: Tried to see how QtCreator runs it.. found only: `Starting /home/user/Projects/Project-build-desktop/Project...`

Comment: Aha, the problem is that when you click the application, it runs from $HOME. If you want to run the application from a specific directory, you need to cd to that directory then execute the executable full path. QtCreator does this automatically for you. I suggest you try: 1) the method I posted to get the location of the executable 2) store the location of where to look for the file in a QSettings object.

Answer (score 2):

I found this discussion while searching for a similar solution. I think that the most portable way of opening an external file that has a fixed name (and no dialogs and the user are involved) is to use the [Resource System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).

In my case I created a new resource file with the prefix `/config` and added the file (called `settings.xml`). Inside the code, I don't need to use any path functions at all. I use the resource system instead. Thus a call like `QFile file(":/config/settings.xml")` works fine. Using QT creator 2.0.1 and QT 4.7 on Windows.

Comment: To comment myself, this solution works but has the disadvantage of not being able to modify the XML file since it is converted to a binary resource file. If you need to be able to modify the XML contents and execute the application without recompiling, use one of the rest solutions provided here.

Answer (score 0):

My tip is this : **name of the file** + **the absolute path to it** before opening it. For that I call the method `applicationDirPath` on our `QCoreApplication` object (the `a` object in my case), which returns us the path to the executable of the application. No need going through the `argv` array. That's it and works

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   const QString fileName = "someJsonFile.JSON";
   const QString currentExecDir = a.applicationDirPath();
   QFile myFile(currentExecDir + '/' + fileName);
   if (myFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    qDebug()<< "The file "<< fileName<< " has been opened successfully";
   }
   else {
     qDebug()<< "Failed to open file "<< fileName<< " in "<< currentExecDir;
   }
   return a.exec();
}
```

**NOTE**
*Please see the Qt docs for the* `applicationDirPath` *method, because it assumes that the current directory has not been changed by the application*