# What is the most portable way of copying a file to the output project directory?

Tags: file, copy, project, qt-creator, qmake

I want to copy an XML file to the output directory (debug/release). I don't want to do it using the resource system because this doesn't allow me to modify the file without recompiling. [5314464](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731736/qt-how-to-open-a-file-in-current-dir-or-whats-wrong-with-this/5314464) shows how to open the file in a portable way, but I couldn't find a good solution for copying it (obviously I want to automate this somehow). Solutions like [1740534](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740534/qmake-how-do-i-copy-dll-sos-to-the-output-directory) suggest using the copy command of each operating system but perhaps there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the INSTALLS keyword in your qmake file.  (See [QMake Reference on INSTALLS](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs))

```
stuff_to_copy.path = /path/to/put/it/in
stuff_to_copy.files += file1
stuff_to_copy.files += file1

INSTALLS += stuff_to_copy
```

Having done this, you will need to run "make install" as part of your build process to actually cause the files to be copied.